# Django: trying to pass users first name to template but getting a weird code instead

Tags: django, django-templates, django-users

In views.py I have:

```
def loggedin(request):
   return render_to_response('theDB/loggedin.html', {'first_name': User.first_name })
```

---

In `loggedin.html` I have:

```
<h2>Hi {{ first_name }} you are now logged in!</h2>
<p>Click <a href="/accounts/logout/">here</a> to logout.</p>"
```

---

This is what I get in the browser:

```
Hi "<"django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000019FD7AA7AC8> you are now logged in!
Click here to logout.
```

Instead of seeing the user's first name, I see that weird thing (a unicode object?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User` is the model class, not the current logged in user. You can use `request.user` in your view.

```
def loggedin(request):
    return render(request, 'theDB/loggedin.html', {'first_name': request.user.first_name)
```

Note I have used the `render` shortcut, which is recommended instead of `render_to_response`.

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly as instructed but got the following error: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'first_name'

Comment: If `request.user` is an `AnonymousUser`, that means that you have not logged in. Normally, you would use the [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator to prevent users from accessing the view unless they have logged in.

Comment: I updated the question with more info. I have this to login a user:   def my_view(request):    
username = request.POST['username']    
password = request.POST['password']    
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)    
'    'if user is not None:
'    '    'if user.is_active:    
'    '    'login(request, user)    
'    '    '# Redirect to a success page which is theDB/loggedin.html  else... since I get redirected to loggedin.html, doesn't that mean that the login was successful?

Comment: Debugging your login page is a separate problem, so it would be better to ask a separate question. Django comes with [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) including a login view. I recommend you use these rather than writing your own.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but I generally use libraries for this. You get oauth and external sign-ins this way with ease, and at your discretion. Here's one I've used successfully https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at that and let you know. But from the code I currently have, is my understanding correct? That the login was successful given that it redirected me to the loggedin.html (template bug aside) and thus login_required decorator wouldn't be necessary? (i.e. login_required does the same thing as "if user is not None: if user.is_active then go to loggedin.html ?)

Comment: It's a good idea to use `login_required` even if your login view is working. It protects against a logged out user going to that URL directly. Sorry, I can't help your debug your login view. Since the user is `AnonymousUser`, that suggests that your login is not working, even if it did redirect you.